# MacbookPro Unlock screen with High Sierra

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra, login

My Macbook Pro- 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 is not showing default login/Touch ID screen with background blur effect wallpaper. instead it is poping up some weird screen to login(Attached image). If I create another user then it is showing fine.

This kind of screen is coming only for one existing user.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Screen Saver - Show with Lock option deselected

[image]

Comment: This thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7277756 on Apple's discussion has a user with the same problem. The suggested use is to completely remove McAfee anti-virus. Do you have McAfee installed?

Comment: I dn’t have MACfee/any other Anti virus softwares on my Mac

Answer (score 1):

this is not the login screen - this is a lock screen. This requires user input to authenticate, and assuming one has the correct info to do so, once past this screen, the option for screensaver to require password can be deselected. If this lock screen was driven by properly authorized remote management, there may not be a toggle to disable it.

Comment: Screen Saver - Show with Lock option was deselected already but still it is showing same screen.